# Boiling Point Reversal

Tags: physical-chemistry, boiling-point

If substance A boils at a lower Temperature than substance B under atm. pressure, can it be that under some other condition, say, elevated Pressure or under vacuum a reversal of the trend occurs?

i.e. substance B boiling lower than substance A?

Is this phenomenon known? What are some examples?

In other words, If the vap. pr. of A is higher than B at one given T there's no fundamental reason for that inequality to persist at all temperatures, correct?

Comment: Correct.  The temperature dependence of the vapor pressure depends thermodynamically on the heat of vaporization.  So, depending on the heats of vaporization of the two substances, the vapor pressure curves can cross.

Comment: Thanks Chester! But do they, in practice? I'm just curious since I've never heard qualification of the sort "X is low boiling than Y so long as we are above 500 torr" etc. I guess I could try various Antoine equations & simulate things........

Comment: $$\frac{d\ln P}{d(1/T)}=-\frac{\Delta H}{R}$$  This is the Clausius-Clapeyron equation.  Look in Perry's Chemical Engineer's Handbook or a Thermo book for a graph of vapor pressures as a function of temperature.  Notice all the crossovers.